# Check whether multiple variables exist in python

Tags: python

I want to check whether multiple variables exist in python. I've tried some ways, but I have no idea why this not work in Python.

This is my Python code, I use 'all' in my if condition

```py
feature = [{'a':'A'}]
table = 'demo'
if all(var in locals() for var in ('feature', 'table')):
    print("all exist")
else:
    print("at least one not exists")
```

This output should be "all exist" while it turns out "at least one not exists", which confuse me a lot.

Comment: Why do you need to test whether variables exist?! You should hardcode variables in your code. They exist exactly as you code them. You shouldn't ever need to *test* their existence.

Comment: Also, if you run it outside of a function, there are no locals by definition of thereof.

Comment: "Shouldn't ever" is a strong assertion; for example, if you're writing anything that has to run user-supplied code and extract variables from it, then you may have to deal with variables whose names are not known at "compile-time".

Comment: @bereal, that's not true - in the global scope, `locals()` does return a dictionary with `feature` and `table` as keys. The problem is that `locals()` is being run in a different scope here.

Comment: Maybe you want to check if a value has been assigned to your variable? Then it will be `If value is not None: # code ()`

Comment: @kaya3 oh indeed, sorry.

Comment: @kaya3 Why are you extracting variables from user-supplied code? Those user-supplied *values* should stay in a dict or class.

Comment: Because I write applications where the user-supplied values *are* code, and the output depends on the result of running that code. For example, I have designed a programmable markup language which allows user-defined functions.

Comment: @deceze - I'm guessing they're talking about using `eval` in some sense, but either way I don't think this is the case and definitely an xy problem

Comment: I think it's likely that what the OP is trying to do isn't necessary and there's a better solution to the actual problem; but the question makes sense as a thing that some people might need to do, and the code fails for a subtle rather than trivial reason, so considering the question in isolation, it's a perfectly good question.

Comment: @kaya3 On a subtle technical level, yes, it's a reasonable question. But in my experience the jump to *variable variables* comes way too naturally for many newbies, so I'd always question whether what they're doing makes any sense in the first place. If you're creating programmable markup languages with user defined functions, you're probably aware of the issue and its solution yourself…

Comment: I agree, and your comments are valuable because of the likelihood of beginners asking this question.

Comment: @deceze Just like kaya3 said, this python is provided to users while some variables might be deleted since users thought wouldn't be used. So I have to make sure all these variables exist before the following function invoked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you passed a generator function as the argument to the `all` function, so `locals()` is being called in that generator function's local scope, *not* the scope you called `all` from (where `feature` and `table` are defined).

To diagnose the bug, we can try this:

```py
>>> all(print(locals()) for var in ('feature', 'table'))
{'var': 'feature', '.0': <tuple_iterator object at 0x7fef8edc27f0>}
```

Note how the locals in the generator function's scope are `var` (which holds the key you want to check for) and `.0` which holds a reference to the iterator over the tuple `('feature', 'table')`. Those are the only locals that are needed to do the iteration.

To solve this, call `locals()` from the right scope:

```py
feature = [{'a':'A'}]
table = 'demo'

outer_locals = locals()

if all(var in outer_locals for var in ('feature', 'table')):
    print("all exist")
else:
    print("at least one not exists")
```

Output is now "all exist", as expected.

Answer (score 2):

`locals` sometimes doesn't provide the dict you want, when it is in the same scope of where the variables are defined, i.e `globals` will work here:

```
feature = [{'a':'A'}]
table = 'demo'

if all(var in globals() for var in ('feature', 'table')):
    print("all exist")
else:
    print("at least one not exists")
```

Output:

```
all exist
```

But of course, I agree with @deceze, but @kaya3 proves a point.

Comment: This works assuming the variables are indeed defined in the global scope, but not otherwise.

Comment: I'd imagine this has a big chance of creating false positives